# Creating AVD for android 4.0.3

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I installed packages for Android 4.0.3 but I can't create AVD for it because it is showing No system image installed for this package and I am not getting ARM EABI v7a System Image for api level 15.
I have System image installed for Android 4.4(19). Here are the screen shots of sdk manager and avd manager.
[image: AVD MANAGER]

[image: AVD MANAGER]

Comment: The checkboxes that say show, play with those. Right now it's only set to show new/updates/installed -- but what you're looking for isn't exactly "new". Also, maybe try installing the SDK platform for 4.0.3, maybe you'll get an image  option afterwards -- but try those checkboxes first.

Comment: I tried that but still not showing System Image for level 15

Comment: my sdk manager also doesn't show arm images for platforms I've downloaded nothing for. Try downloading everything else for 4.0.3 and see what then shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that your SDK is incorrectly configured and does not have links to the required resources. To remedy this you can manually edit the `sites-settings.cfg` file, which should be located in one of these locations (you will need to have hidden/system files visible):

```
C:\SDK\.android
C:\Users\[username]\.android
```

The following is the contents of my file, which you can just copy/paste into yours (make a backup first):

```
### Sites Settings for Android SDK Manager
#Fri Jun 27 12:25:33 CAT 2014
@name@https\://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/sys-img.xml=Android x86 System Images
@name@https\://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon-6.xml=Google Inc.
@disabled@http\://dl.htcdev.com/sdk/addon.xml=disabled
@name@https\://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img.xml=Android Wear System Images
@name@http\://dl.htcdev.com/sdk/addon.xml=HTC
@name@https\://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-8.xml=Android Repository
@name@http\://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml=Google Inc.
@version@=1
@name@https\://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img.xml=Android System Images
@name@http\://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/android/addon.xml=Intel Corporation
@disabled@http\://www.mips.com/global/sdk-sys-img.xml=disabled
@name@https\://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img.xml=Android System Images
@name@https\://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml=Intel HAXM
@name@https\://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml=Android Repository
@name@http\://developer.lgmobile.com/sdk/android/repository.xml=LG Electronics
@disabled@http\://www.echobykyocera.com/download/echo_repository.xml=disabled
@disabled@http\://android-sdk-addons.motodevupdate.com/addons.xml=disabled
@name@http\://download-software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/android/sys-img.xml=Intel Corporation System Images
@disabled@http\://innovator.samsungmobile.com/android/repository/repository.xml=disabled
@name@http\://innovator.samsungmobile.com/android/repository/repository.xml=Samsung Electronics
@name@http\://www.mips.com/global/sdk-sys-img.xml=MIPS Technologies System Images
@name@https\://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/android-wear-sys-img.xml=Experimental Android Wear System Images
@disabled@http\://developer.sonymobile.com/edk/android/repository.xml=disabled
@name@http\://android-sdk-addons.motodevupdate.com/addons.xml=Motorola Mobility, Inc.
@disabled@http\://developer.lgmobile.com/sdk/android/repository.xml=disabled
@name@https\://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/mips/sys-img.xml=Android MIPS System Images
@name@https\://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-9.xml=Android Repository
@name@https\://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml=Android Repository
@name@http\://developer.sonymobile.com/edk/android/repository.xml=Sony Mobile Communications AB
@name@https\://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml=Google Inc.
@name@https\://dl-ssl.google.com/glass/gdk/addon.xml=Glass Development Kit, Google Inc.
@name@https\://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img.xml=Android TV System Images
@name@http\://no.source=Local Packages
@name@http\://www.echobykyocera.com/download/echo_repository.xml=KYOCERA Corporation
@name@https\://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/addon-x86.xml=Google Inc. (x86 System Images)
```

Also, make sure that your firewall is not blocking the SDK manager.

---

If this does not fix your problem (and you are in a hurry), you can download the image manually at the following url:

http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sysimg_armv7a-15_r02.zip

After downloading, extract the contents of the zip file to `C:\SDK\system-images\android-15\` (create the folders if they don't exist). Then re-launch the AVD and it should pick-up the new system image.

Answer (score 0):

You chose android 4.0.3 API level 15 target device and you have no System Image for this device. So (1)Install System Image for this API level or (2) Choose Android 4.4 API level 19 as target device that you already have System Image for.

Answer (score 0):

Toward the bottom of the SDK manager window, you have selected to only show the installed components. Uncheck this option so that you can view the components that are available to be installed. This will include the system images which you are missing.