# Android Studio and SDK Tools 25.1.1 issue

Tags: android, android-studio

Just download fresh Android SDK to my linux box and cant find the way to install emulator images.

```
$ uname -a
Linux 4.2.0-23-generic #28~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 31 13:40:42 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$ ./android  --verbose --clear-cache list sdk -a

    SDK Manager repository: manifest cache cleared.
    Refresh Sources:
      Fetching https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
      Validate XML
      Parse XML
      Fetched Add-ons List successfully
      Refresh Sources
      Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml
      Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml
      Parse XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml
      Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
      Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
      Parse XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
      Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon-6.xml
      Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon-6.xml
      Parse XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon-6.xml
      Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/glass/addon.xml
      Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/glass/addon.xml
      Parse XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/glass/addon.xml
      Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
      Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
      Parse XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
      Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img.xml
      Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img.xml
      Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img.xml
      Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img.xml
      Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/addon.xml
    Refresh Sources:
      Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img.xml
      Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img.xml
      Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img.xml
      Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img.xml
      Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/addon.xml
    Packages available for installation or update: 98
       1- Android SDK Tools, revision 25.1.1
       2- Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 23.1
       3- Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 24 rc1
       4- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 24 rc2
       5- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 23.0.3
       6- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 23.0.2
       7- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 23.0.1
       8- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 23 (Obsolete)
       9- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 22.0.1
      10- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 22 (Obsolete)
      11- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21.1.2
      12- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21.1.1 (Obsolete)
      13- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21.1 (Obsolete)
      14- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21.0.2 (Obsolete)
      15- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21.0.1 (Obsolete)
      16- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21 (Obsolete)
      17- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 20
      18- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.1
      19- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.0.3 (Obsolete)
      20- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.0.2 (Obsolete)
      21- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.0.1 (Obsolete)
      22- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19 (Obsolete)
      23- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 18.1.1 (Obsolete)
      24- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 18.1 (Obsolete)
      25- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 18.0.1 (Obsolete)
      26- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 17 (Obsolete)
      27- Documentation for Android SDK, API 23, revision 1
      28- SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 3
      29- SDK Platform Android N Preview, revision 1
      30- SDK Platform Android 5.1.1, API 22, revision 2
      31- SDK Platform Android 5.0.1, API 21, revision 2
      32- SDK Platform Android 4.4W.2, API 20, revision 2
      33- SDK Platform Android 4.4.2, API 19, revision 4
      34- SDK Platform Android 4.3.1, API 18, revision 3
      35- SDK Platform Android 4.2.2, API 17, revision 3
      36- SDK Platform Android 4.1.2, API 16, revision 5
      37- SDK Platform Android 4.0.3, API 15, revision 5
      38- SDK Platform Android 4.0, API 14, revision 4
      39- SDK Platform Android 3.2, API 13, revision 1
      40- SDK Platform Android 3.1, API 12, revision 3
      41- SDK Platform Android 3.0, API 11, revision 2
      42- SDK Platform Android 2.3.3, API 10, revision 2
      43- SDK Platform Android 2.3.1, API 9, revision 2
      44- SDK Platform Android 2.2, API 8, revision 3
      45- SDK Platform Android 2.1, API 7, revision 3
      46- SDK Platform Android 2.0.1, API 6, revision 1 (Obsolete)
      47- SDK Platform Android 2.0, API 5, revision 1 (Obsolete)
      48- SDK Platform Android 1.6, API 4, revision 3 (Obsolete)
      49- SDK Platform Android 1.5, API 3, revision 4 (Obsolete)
      50- SDK Platform Android 1.1, API 2, revision 1 (Obsolete)
      51- Google APIs, Android API 23, revision 1
      52- Google APIs, Android API 22, revision 1
      53- Google APIs, Android API 21, revision 1
      54- Google APIs, Android API 19, revision 18
      55- Glass Development Kit Preview, Android API 19, revision 11
      56- Google APIs, Android API 18, revision 4
      57- Google APIs, Android API 17, revision 4
      58- Google APIs, Android API 16, revision 4
      59- Google APIs, Android API 15, revision 3
      60- Google APIs, Android API 14, revision 2 (Obsolete)
      61- Google APIs, Android API 13, revision 1 (Obsolete)
      62- Google TV Addon, Android API 13, revision 1 (Obsolete)
      63- Google APIs, Android API 12, revision 1 (Obsolete)
      64- Google TV Addon, Android API 12, revision 2 (Obsolete)
      65- Google APIs, Android API 11, revision 1 (Obsolete)
      66- Google APIs, Android API 10, revision 2 (Obsolete)
      67- Google APIs, Android API 9, revision 2 (Obsolete)
      68- Google APIs, Android API 8, revision 2 (Obsolete)
      69- Google APIs, Android API 7, revision 1 (Obsolete)
      70- Google APIs, Android API 6, revision 1 (Obsolete)
      71- Google APIs, Android API 5, revision 1 (Obsolete)
      72- Google APIs, Android API 4, revision 2 (Obsolete)
      73- Google APIs, Android API 3, revision 3 (Obsolete)
      74- Sources for Android SDK, API 23, revision 1
      75- Sources for Android SDK, API 22, revision 1
      76- Sources for Android SDK, API 21, revision 1
      77- Sources for Android SDK, API 20, revision 1
      78- Sources for Android SDK, API 19, revision 2
      79- Sources for Android SDK, API 18, revision 1
      80- Sources for Android SDK, API 17, revision 1
      81- Sources for Android SDK, API 16, revision 2
      82- Sources for Android SDK, API 15, revision 2
      83- Sources for Android SDK, API 14, revision 1 (Obsolete)
      84- GPU Debugging tools, revision 1.0.3
      85- Android Support Repository, revision 28
      86- Android Support Library, revision 23.2.1
      87- Google AdMob Ads SDK, revision 11 (Obsolete)
      88- Google Analytics App Tracking SDK, revision 3 (Obsolete)
      89- Android Auto Desktop Head Unit emulator, revision 1.1
      90- Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library, revision 3 (Obsolete)
      91- Google Play services for Froyo, revision 12 (Obsolete)
      92- Google Play services, revision 29
      93- Google Repository, revision 25
      94- Google Play APK Expansion library, revision 1
      95- Google Play Licensing Library, revision 1
      96- Google Play Billing Library, revision 5
      97- Android Auto API Simulators, revision 1
      98- Google Web Driver, revision 2
```

Where is the emulator images?

In advance, i did the full fresh Android Studio installation as well, and during initial configuration it was not able to install emulator images too and interrupted with an error `The following SDK component was not installed: sys-img-x86-addon-google_apis-google-23`

How to setup most recent development environment to be able to build and run/debug applications in emulator?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25711138/1009132), perhaps your SDK is incorrectly configured. Mine looks like this:

[image]

[image]

Press `Ctrl+H` to see hidden folders and files on Linux, the location is:

```
/home/YOUR_USER/.android/sites-settings.cfg
```

---

**Previous response:** Use the `extended` option to see the new names:

```
./android --verbose --clear-cache list sdk -a -e |more
```

[image]

You can also launch the android sdk manager and select the packages to be installed:

```
./android update sdk
```

[image]

According to [Android Developers Blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2016/04/android-studio-2-0.html) about Android 2.0 release

> Android Emulator - The new emulator ... **Like a physical device, the official Android emulator also includes [Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/?utm_campaign=android_launch_studio_040716&utm_source=anddev&utm_medium=blog) built-in**, so you can test out more API functionality...
>
> Trying out the new emulator is as easy as updating your SDK Tools to 25.1.1 or higher, create a fresh Android Virtual Device using one of the recommended x86 system images and you are ready to go. Learn more about the Android Emulator by checking out the documentation.

You can [use Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36509151/using-android-studio-2-0-emulator-with-google-services) or execute a command like this:

```
./android create avd --force -n test -t android-23 -g google_apis
```

Comment: Now it works fine. I didn't try to change anything, it just starts to work after a while. It looks like something was broken on google side during to AS 2.0 transition.