# Using Android Studio 2.0 emulator with Google Services

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, google-play-services

According to an article in the Android Developers Blog, regarding the [release of Android Studio 2.0](http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2016/04/android-studio-2-0.html):

> Android Emulator - The new emulator runs ~3x faster than Android’s previous emulator, and with ADB enhancements you can now push apps and data 10x faster to the emulator than to a physical device. **Like a physical device, the official Android emulator also includes [Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/?utm_campaign=android_launch_studio_040716&utm_source=anddev&utm_medium=blog) built-in**, so you can test out more API functionality. Finally, the new emulator has rich new features to manage calls, battery, network, GPS, and more.

Great! That's exactly what we need. Later on the article they explain how we can get Google Play Services in our emulators.

> Trying out the new emulator is as easy as updating your SDK Tools to 25.1.1 or higher, create a fresh Android Virtual Device using one of the recommended x86 system images and you are ready to go. Learn more about the Android Emulator by checking out the documentation.

I have SDK Tools 25.1.1 installed. I have a fresh Android Virtual Device running x86 system image.

No Google play services :-(

What am I missing?

Comment: Please note that I am not asking how to install google play services on my emulator. There are many questions on SO that address that. I want to use the one that was **built-in**.

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34291902/android-studio-emulator-does-not-come-with-play-store-for-api-23

Answer (score 1):

When you create your virtual device, be sure to choose the one "with Google APIs".  If that isn't an option, you will have to use the Android SDK manager to download the Google APIs for each API level you want to work with.

Comment: Do you mind if I ask you where can I find "with Google APIs"?

Comment: If you have them installed, you will see that text when you go to create an emulator instance.  if you don't have them installed, you will have to download them as I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: OK... I have them installed. Beside my virtual devices I see "Google APIs". Still no built-in google services :(

Comment: What exactly is telling you that play services is not available?

Comment: if I go on `My actual phone -> Settings -> Apps` I can see Google Play Services. If I go on the `emulator -> Settings -> Apps` there is no Google Play Services.

Comment: Then you're not using a Google APIs emulator.  My Android M emulator with Google APIs show a Google Play services app installed, and I did not add it myself.