# Android 4.0.3 API15 doesn't show in AVD manager

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-virtual-device

I'm having a problem with AVD, similar to this:

[Creating AVD for android 4.0.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707692/creating-avd-for-android-4-0-3)

But the solution didn't work out for me.

Here are a few screens of my sdk manager installed packages:

[image: My SDK packages with (almost) everything installed]

The rest:

[image: The rest that didn't fit]

Also here in my folder:

[image: My sdk folder with Android 15]

But now in my avd, I have a preconfigured VD installed manually with a exe script.

[image: the virtual device that is supposed to work]

But it can't load. I tried to edit the image, but here's my avd image selection

[image: AvD manager screenshot]

As you can see I have everything but API 15...

Comment: Have you tried remove and reinstall API15 image in Android SDK manager (`tools/android`)?

Comment: It was uninstalled at first, so I installed it before doing anything.

Comment: Ok I have progress. I created a new AVD with the AVD manager standalone, it seems to be working now. both of them. weird.